# Trying to set up iPhone-gcc compiler

Tags: iphone, gcc, compilation, header

So I've installed iPhone-gcc, make and ldid from cydia, i can't compile
yet though because I don't have the headers setup. I've looked around and there's not really much info on setting up the headers, librarys and frameworks. I just need to know where to extract them from the sdk and where to place them on my iPhone.

I've been trying to get this to work for a while, Any help would be great.
Thanks
Adam M

Answer (score 1):

I found everything in package `com.bigboss.20toolchain`.
After installation, I found headers:

```
root # aptitude install com.bigboss.20toolchain
root # dpkg -L com.bigboss.20toolchain | grep stdio\.h         
/var/include/stdio.h
/var/include/xlocale/_stdio.h
root #
```

Answer (score 0):

This script automatically setup iphone toolchain for you, runs on Mac OS X, thanks to @rpetrich. http://gist.github.com/403608

First, remember to 
`apt-get remove iphone-gcc` on your iphone
before running this script on your mac, if you don't want to collect headers files from iphone sdk, follow the Darwin arm part of the script and I think you should be good. This works for me out of the box.